# 3rd party DLL works in Console application but throws protected memory error in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, console-application, dllimport, access-violation

I am working with a USB I/O unit which has a 3rd party DLL downloadable from the company's website (DEDITEC, "delib64.dll"). I work in Visual Studio 2013.

There is a C# "wrapper"-class from the same company, which just contains a bunch of constants and a lot of DllImport-wrapped static methods. This all works beautifully when I write a Console application and use the wrapper class from there.

However, when I include identical code in a WPF program, it aborts with a "read/write access to protected memory" exception on first call to the wrapper/DllImported functions. I do not have access to the DLL's source code.

I have a solid UNIX background, but my Windows skills are not yet good enough. I would therefore like to ask: where do I start searching for this kind of error?

It *feels* like a question of privileges, threading or similar. I feel that there is a clue in the fact that the Console application works without me doing anything special, when the same code doesn't work in a WPF application - I just don't know quite enough to see the clue or know what to search for. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like code from the DLL is trampling on something that WPF uses. Everything in C#/WPF (unless you start throwing around the unsafe keyword) is safe and won't do things like that, but the unmanaged code in the DLL may well be directly accessing memory in the program's address space if it so pleased.

One workaround would be to write a console application and then call that from the WPF application (I know that feels dirty, but it's an option).

You may want to contact the company responsible (though I realize that's not always the easiest thing to do, as many places won't respond timely or at all) since they can easily answer questions about it with the code in front of them and either identify the problem to work around or fix.